# Почему не происходит запись в БД?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Всех приветствую.
Пару лет назад писал бота на python, добавлял запись в бд при нажатии кнопки 'start'
Сейчас понадобился данный функционал, скопировал но бот не запускается. Помогите решить проблему.

```
import telebot
import sqlite3
import const

from sqlite3 import Error
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(const.token)

with sqlite3.connect('my.db') as db:

def create_tables():
    users_query = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS
                        (user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                        username TEXT,
                        first_name TEXT,
                        last_name TEXT,
                        reg_date TEXT);'''
    post_sql_query(users_query)



def register_user(user, username, first_name, last_name):
    user_check_query = f'SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE user_id = {user};'
    user_check_data = post_sql_query(user_check_query)
    if not user_check_data:
        insert_to_db_query = f'INSERT INTO USERS (user_id, username, first_name,  last_name, reg_date) VALUES ({user}, "{username}", "{first_name}", "{last_name}", "{ctime()}");'
        post_sql_query(insert_to_db_query )



def post_sql_query(sql_query):
    with sqlite3.connect('my.db') as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql_query)
        except Error:
            pass
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        return result

create_tables()




@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def startpg(message):
    startmenu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
    startmenu.row('qq', 'qq')
    startmenu.row('qq', 'qq')
    startmenu.row('qq', 'qq')
    startmenu.row('qq', '2 страница')
    register_user(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.username,
                  message.from_user.first_name, message.from_user.last_name)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f' Привет {message.from_user.first_name}  я  qq  ', reply_markup=startmenu)
```

Comment: Так «бот не запускается» или «не происходит запись в БД»?

Comment: В общем у меня была закомментирована строка register_user в функции def startpg, после меню. Бот работал, но запись в бд не велась, я раскомментировал ее и бот перестал стартовать. Если эту строку убрать бот будет работать, но записи в бд не поступают.

Comment: Я не понмю почему я закомментировал эту строку, возможно из за нее у меня не запускался старый бот. Но если кто то может помочь с этим, я буду благодарен.